# What is the most pythonic way to relationate 2 pandas dataframe? Based on a key value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, vaex

So, I work on a place and here I use A LOT of Python (Pandas) and the data keeps getting bigger and bigger, last month I was working with a few hundred thousand rows, weeks after that I was working with a few million rows and now I am working with 42 million rows. Most of my work is just take a dataframe and for each row, I need to consult in another dataframe its "equivalent" and process the data, sometimes just merge but more often i need to do a function with the equivalent data. Back in the days with a few hundred thousand rows, it was ok to just use apply and a simple filter but now it is **EXTREMELY SLOW**. Recently I've switched to vaex which is way faster than pandas on every aspect but apply, and after some time searching I found that apply is the last resource and should be used only if u haven't another option. So, is there another option? I really don't know

Some code to explain how I was doing this entire time:

```
def get_secondary(row: pd.DataFrame):
    cnae = row["cnae_fiscal"]
    cnpj = row["cnpj"]
    # cnaes is another dataframe
    secondary = cnaes[cnaes.cnpj == cnpj]
    return [cnae] + list(secondary["cnae"].values)

empresas["cnae_secundarios"] = empresas.apply(get_secondary, axis=1)
```

This isn't the only use case, as I said.

Comment: Can you include some samples for `empresas` and `cnaes`?

Comment: `empresas` have too many columns, but here are some: https://i.imgur.com/ujKrfCq.png


`cnaes` only have 3: https://i.imgur.com/xEnoJ7h.png


on `empresas` CNPJ are unique, on `cnaes` it isn't.

but this isn't the only use case, as i said.

Comment: Try: `empresas["cnae_secundarios"] = empresas["cnpj"].map(cnaes.groupby("cnpj")["cnae"].apply(list))`